# WSO2 IS 5.0.0 saml authentication always redirects to localhost

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm playing with travelocity sample application, but I'm having a problem:
when I access the application at `10.0.3.124:8080/travelocity.com` I end up at `https://localhost:9444/commonauth?SAMLRequest=...` even though I configured the "host" parameter in carbon.xml. I've also searched for localhost in authenticators.xml and application-authentication.xml and found IdentityProviderSSOServiceURL that i changed from localhost to machine ip.
I'm on a laptop and my application server and IS istances run on a different machine with the 10.0.3.124 IP.
I successfully access the IS admin console.
Where's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I also had to configure the `<MgtHostName>10.0.3.124</MgtHostName>` in carbon.xml.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a file named identity.xml in side IS_HOME/repository/conf which carries following configuration.

```
<SSOService>
    <IdentityProviderURL>https://localhost:9443/samlsso</IdentityProviderURL>
```

Please configuring this with your environment parameters.

Thanks,
Pushpalanka